# I never actually get help on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, questions, scope

Based on my experience on this website, the only answers I see on this are answers to questions that easily could have been answered by the asker himself if he actually had knowledge of how to use Google. Questions like how to install all the packages listed in a text file in Linux are already covered in its documentation. Based on what I've seen, anything that can't be answered with a quick Google search gets shunned by the answerers.

I am confused about how to get help here, if it's even possible.

Comment: How many questions have you asked? How long have the questions been available before coming here to say that you aren't getting answers fast enough? What sites are you asking on (not everything has people itching to answer questions 7 by 24)?

Comment: "questions that easily could have been answered by the asker himself if he actually had knowledge of how to use Google" will typically attract downvotes

Comment: See, this very question can't be answered easily by Google and yet you got an answer. Wonderful, isn't it?

Answer (score 9):

It appears that you [haven't really *tried* to get help](https://stackexchange.com/users/6760371/fancyname?tab=accounts) - you [asked one question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248465/a-script-or-series-of-commands-that-turns-off-wlan0-when-eth0-is-not-connected), and less than an hour later, came here and said you were getting "shunned".

Not everyone is sitting at their computers waiting to answer every question as soon as it appears, but very few questions on the vast majority of SE sites are ignored.

Give it some time.  Give it a chance.  You'll get what you're looking for almost every time.